# Ruby on Rails. Интеграционный тест выдает ошибку unknown keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, тестирование

Изучаю рельсы по книге Майкла Харта. Создана модель данных и соответственно интеграционные тесты для проверки успешности и не успешности создания пользователя. 
Выдает ошибку unknown keyword: user

2) Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_invalid_signup_information:
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: user
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
    test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:7:in`block in '

Я понимаю, что возможна семантическая ошибка, хотя и перепроверял и копировал напрямую из книги. Код теста

```
test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, user: { name: "",
                              email: "user@invalid",
                              password: "foo",
                              password_confirmation: "bar" }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
  end
```

Но при этом сама модель работает адекватно и при попытке ввести не валидные значения не дает это сделать. Код контролера

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,
                                :password,:password_confirmation)
 end
end
```

И сам класс модели

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположу, что интеграционные тесты, в отличие от модульных, принимают
параметры явно:

```ruby
user_params = {
  name: "",
  kmail: "user@invalid",
  password: "foo",
  password_confirmation: "bar",
}
post users_path, params: { user: user_params }
```

Comment: это то, что было нужно  - тест проходит успешно. Спасибо @Ainar-G

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение на Stack. Синтаксис в Rails 5 и Rails 4 отличается, подобный нюанс описан  с теме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289420/railstutorial-chapter-8-tests-failing

Привожу код:

```
    require 'test_helper'

    class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

        test "invalid signup information" do
          get signup_path
          assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
            post users_path, params: { user: { name: "",
                                                   email: "user@invalid",
                                                   password: "foo",
                                         password_confirmation: "bar"} }
          end
        assert_template 'users/new'
      end
    end
```

---

PS Как ни странно, синтаксис приведенный для Rails 4 решил проблему. Это при том, что я использую Rails 5.2.4.3

Comment: Пожалуста, примите к сведению, данный ресурс не является форумом. Поэтому. вы либо даёте ответ, либо задаёте новый вопрос. Предыдушее ваше сообщение в этой теме пожалуйста удалите. Если по решению в этом ответе у вас остались какие то неясности, то задайте новый вопрос.